# oraclesql view question

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Q. when i create a view on sql browser it show insufficient priviligies,so how i can create a view?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to be granted the CREATE VIEW or CREATE ANY VIEW system privilege on the schema you're working on.

Answer (score 3):

You will also need to have direct SELECT privileges on any tables referenced in your view. SELECT permissions granted via a role will not work.  See [CREATE VIEW prerequisites](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm#i2065510).